# Difference between wiedererkennen and erkennen

Tags: meaning, verb

I have read/heard the following sentence:

> Einen Zauberer muss man wiedererkennen.

Context: A child is wearing a skeleton costume to go to the school and his mother asks him to take the costume off and wear normal clothes. Then the boy says the sentence above.

According to Word Reference, one of the meanings of "[erkennen](https://www.wordreference.com/deen/erkennen)" is "to recognize" and that's also the meaning of "[wiedererkennen](https://www.wordreference.com/deen/wiedererkennen)". Supposedly the "wieder" prefix should add a meaning of "again", but "recognize again" does not make sense in the sentence above. Is there any difference between "erkennen" and "wiedererkennen" in this context?

Source: Dark series, 1st season, 1st episode, 10:32 minutes

Comment: You probably meant "Zauberer" instead of "Zauberen".

Comment: A magician/conjurer/enchanter/illusionist is a *Zauberer* in German (*erer* at the end). This is derived from the verb *zaubern* (*ern* at the end) (zaubern = to conjure, to perform magic tricks) which again is derived from the noun *Zauber* (*er* at the end) which means magic, but also allurement, charm, attraction. The word *Zauberen* (with *eren* at the end) does not exist in German. I corrected this for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The English translation, who's meaning is as close as possible to the meaning of the German verb *wiedererkennen* would be

> re-recognize

> Einen Zauberer muss man **wieder**erkennen.
>
> A magician must be **re**-recognizable.
> <sup>Ein Zauberer muss **wieder**erkennbar sein.</sup>
> You need to be able to **re**-recognize a magician.
> <sup>Man muss einen Zauberer **wieder**erkennen können.</sup>

But this is unusual in English. The german sentence means: Once you have learned what a magician looks like, you need to be able to recognize him later **again.**

Another issue is, that the grammatical construction used in the German sentence can't be used in English. I gave you two possible English translations and their back-translations into German. All Sentences mean pretty the same.

The prefix *wieder-* means *again.* It means, that something, that already has happened before, happens again.

> Wir müssen den alten Zustand **wieder**herstellen.
> We need to **re**store the old state. (literal: We need to **re**-produce the old state.)
>
> Herbert musste nach einem Herzinfarkt **wieder**belebt werden.
> Herbert had to be **re**animated after a heart attack.
>
> Ich freue mich, dich **wieder**zusehen.
> I'm happy to see you **again.** (literal: I'm happy to **re**-see you.)
>
> Herr Gruber wurde als Präsident des Schachklubs **wieder**gewählt.
> Mr. Gruber was **re**-elected as president of the chess club.

---

What makes re-recognize so weird in English is the fact, that **re**cognize already contains this *re-* prefix. The word *recognize* came into English from the French language, which had borrowed it from old Latin.

Latin ***re**cognoscere* is composed from *re-* (again) and *cognoscere* = to know, to get to know. So the origin meaning of English *recognize* is *to re-know.* And this meaning is still contained in the meaning of the English word. So, in English it makes not much sense to say *to re-re-know.* How can you repeat something that already is a repetition? This makes no sense.

But the German verb *erkennen* does not contain this repetitive meaning. The German verb *kennen* also means *to know*, similar to the latin word *cognoscere,* but the German prefix *er-* is not related to any repetition. The prefix *er-*, that you often see in German verbs means, that something has come to an end successfully. So, the original meaning of the German verb *erkennen* was not *»I re-know it«* but *»I have successfully learned in the past what it looks/sounds/feels like, and now I use this knowledge to identify it«.*

Comment: I've noticed that German verb prefixes allow a great deal of precision when it comes to meaning, more precision than is generally possible in English. For example DWDS also lists *aberkennen*, *anerkennen*, and "zuerkennen" as prefixed forms of *erkennen*, which in turn is a prefixed form of *kennen*. I think the trick for learners is to discover how each prefix may affect meaning. This isn't foolproof, for example the connection between *holen* and *wiederholen* is tenuous, but in most cases it's possible to guess the meaning without a trip to a dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

As to my knowledge there is no separate english word for "wiedererkennen". It means specifically to recognize something you remember having recognized before already. "Erkennen" means to understand who or what a person is. i.e.:

> Ich erkenne, daß du Englisch als Muttersprache sprichst.
> <sub>I recognize (notice, understand) you are an english native speaker.</sub>

Whereas:

> Du hast dich so verändert, ich hätte dich kaum wiedererkannt.
> <sub>You changed so much i barely recognized you.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

***erkennen*** – to understand the true nature of something that you see for the first time

Example

The policeman has never see the thief before, but when he sees the man running away carrying a purse, he recognizes the thief by his behavior and the stolen goods. The policeman might say: *Ich erkenne den Dieb!*, meaning: I have never seen this person before, but I understand that this person is the thief we are looking for.

***wiedererkennen*** – to recognize something you have seen before

Example

The policeman, when he apprehends the thief, realizes that he has seen the man before in other circumstances. He might say: *Ich erkenne Sie wieder!* meaning: At first I thought I had never seen you before, but now I realize that I already know you.

---

In your example, the boy probably used the wrong word. When he says "Einen Zauberer muss man wiedererkennen können", this means that he wants to be recognized as the sorcerer by those who have seen him in that role before. If on the other hand he wants to express his desire to be recognized as a sorcerer even by those who haven't yet met him, then "Einen Zauberer muss man erkennen können" would be correct.

As you see, I have added *können* (to be able to) to the end of both phrases. Without *können* the phrases don't make much sense.

- *Einen Zauberer muss man erkennen können.* "A sorcerer must be recognizable", literally "One must be able to recognize a sorcerer."
- *Einen Zauberer muss man wiedererkennen können.* "A sorcerer must always be recognizable", literally "One must be able to recognize a sorcerer that one already knows."
- *Einen Zauberer muss man erkennen.* "You have to recognize a sorcerer", meaning even if the sorcerer does not carry any outward signs of his profession